# Write to response using Action filter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When I use `context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write` or `context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync` inside an `ActionFilterAttribute` I get errors in the pipeline that the response has already started.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
```

Exception is better described in this issue [Unable to write to response using Action filter - OnActionExecuted method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2296)

One comment says that a solution is to **end the request in the filter**, which would work in my case, but I have no idea how to do it.
I tried using `Flush`, `CompleteAsync`, assigning value to `context.Result`, which says will short-circuit the remaining filter, but it didn't work.

What is the right way to end the request/response inside a filter?

Edit:
Example of a filter that throws the error:

```cs
[HttpGet, MyFilter]
public ContentResult MyAction()
{
    return new ContentResult() {Content = "test"};
}

public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        // Get the response object from the context
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        // Write some data to the response
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.WriteAsync("This is some data from the filter!").Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**

Set the `context.Result = null;` (short-circuit the filters) in `OnActionExecuted`, and then write the desired data in `OnResultExecutionAsync` using `Write`, `WriteAsync`, `CopyToAsync` or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below:

```
public class Myfilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            context.Result = new ContentResult() { Content="....",ContentType="text/plain"};
        }
    }
```

It works now:

[image]